# Find the ${PROJECT_DIR} for an Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I figure out what my absolute `${PROJECT_DIR}` path is for my Xcode project? Is there a way to print this in Terminal? How?

Comment: I am also interested that question. Did you find any solution? I need it to create a git hook. So I don't want to run the script while building in xcode. I use a ruby script.

Answer (score 37):

Build Settings -> Preprocess Macros

```
PROJECT_DIR=@\""$PROJECT_DIR"\"

BUILD_ROOT=@\""$(BUILD_ROOT)"\"
```

Then you can log it directly

```
NSLog(@"project dir=%@, BUILD_ROOT_=%@", PROJECT_DIR, BUILD_ROOT);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do also on Build Phases?

Answer (score 31):

Run this from Terminal

For a project:

```
xcodebuild -project yourProject.xcodeproj -target yourTarget -showBuildSettings | grep PROJECT_DIR
```

For a workspace:

```
xcodebuild -workspace yourWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme yourScheme -showBuildSettings | grep PROJECT_DIR
```

As you can see, you can retrieve any other build settings value

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting method is using a Run Script Phase in Build phases:

[image]

Then paste this script that will modify a swift file in your project

```
fileContent="// DO NOT EDIT,
// THIS IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED FILE

//  params.swift
//

import Foundation
class Params {
    static let srcRoot: String = \"${PROJECT_DIR}\"
}"
echo "${SRCROOT}/YourProjectFolderName/params.swift"
echo "$fileContent" > ${SRCROOT}/YourProjectFolderName/params.swift`
```

Make sure you added Params.swift in you project.